# How to find out a record with special character not matching a type of format having the same special character?

Tags: sql, postgresql, zip, postgis, street-address

I am querying using SQL on a zip-code column for checking which records in the column zipcodes do not match the format using like clause.

I tried finding the count of records which match the format. Then I tried which zip records have a hyphen or '-' in it. The count is different.

I want to find out which records are the one that has the hyphen '-' and do not match the format of XXXXX-XXXX.

Also, I do not think the '^' negate symbol works here because it is not in square brackets '[]'. Tried that but did not work

Queries I tried:

select count(*) from zipcode_table where zipcode_column like '%-%'

select count(*) from zipcode_table where zipcode_column like '_____-____'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select count(*)
from zipcode_table
where zipcode_column like '%-%' and          -- has a hyphen
      zipcode_column not like '_____-____';  -- but not in the right place
```

You might really want to check for digits in the other positions:

```
where zipcode_column like '%-%' and             -- has a hyphen
      zipcode_column !~ '^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$';  -- but not in the right
```

Comment: Appreciate the high-quality response, Gordon. What is the $ symbol for? Also, there is a '^', a 'not' and a bitwise not '~'.  Could you help me out in understanding how that works?

Comment: @VishwalShah . . . These are regular expression constructs.  Well, the `~` and `!~` are Postgres constructs for regular expression match and not match respectively.  The `^` and `$` in the regular expression itself are for anchoring the pattern at the beginning and end of the string (that is, matching the entire string).

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS all,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE zipcode LIKE '_____-____') AS correct_format,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE zipcode LIKE '%-%' AND zipcode NOT LIKE '_____-____') AS incorrect_format,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE zipcode NOT LIKE '%-%') AS no_hyphen
FROM zipcode
```